# conversion operator overload : gcc vs clang problem

Tags: c++, templates, conversion-operator

I am trying to write a basic std::any alternative to use in my code, the reason is that i want to replace the templated std::any_cast with a conversion operator.

the use case is to add some introspection/reflection to structure and finally be able to ask a structure for its exposed members and access them by name ( as with a key in std::map ).

added functions to structure should be potentially virtual, templated class will not work.

the code actually look like this :

```
   // "std::any" like type that hold a "reference" to any type using a void*
   // -> keep track of original type using "std::type_info"
   // -> provide a "conversion operator" instead of "std::any_cast<T>" 
   // -> default initialized aRef object will only fail with std::bad_cast{}
  
   struct aRef {
       constexpr aRef() : ptr(nullptr), is_const(false), type(typeid(void)) { }

       template<typename T> explicit aRef(T* in) : ptr(in), is_const(false), type(typeid(T)) { }

       template<typename T> explicit aRef(const T* in) : ptr(const_cast<T*>(in)), is_const(true), type(typeid(T)) { }

       template<typename T> operator T&() {
          std::cout<<"operator T&() ";
          if (is_const) std::cout<<"----> make compiler issue an error !!! "<<std::endl;
          else          std::cout<<std::endl;
          if (typeid(T) == type) return *( static_cast<T*>(ptr) );
          else                   throw  std::bad_cast{};
       }

       template<typename T> operator const T&(){
          std::cout<<"operator const T&() "<<std::endl;
          if (typeid(T) == type) return *( static_cast<T*>(ptr) );
          else                   throw  std::bad_cast{};
       }


       private :
          void* const ptr;
          const bool is_const;
          std::type_info const& type;
   };

// what it should achieve : 
//       T& = aRef(      T*)   --> ok      
//       T& = aRef(const T*)   --> not ok, break constness 
//       T  = aRef(      T*)   --> ok      
//       T  = aRef(const T*)   --> ok    
// const T& = aRef(      T*)   --> ok   
// const T& = aRef(const T*)   --> ok   


// the structure to instrument
struct MDATA {
   double A;
   double B;

  // instrumentation code , functions can be polymorphic 
  // functions only -> zero overhead in size
   aRef operator[](const std::string&  key) {
      if      (key == "A")   return aRef(&A);
      else if (key == "B")   return aRef(&B);
      else                   return aRef();
   }

   aRef operator[](const std::string&  key) const {
      if      (key == "A")   return aRef(&A);
      else if (key == "B")   return aRef(&B);
      else                   return aRef();
   }

};

// dummy function 
void do_something(const double& x) { }

int main () {

   MDATA data {0.2,1.2};

// T& = aRef( T*)   --> ok      
{
  std::cout<<" T& = aRef( T*)... ";
  double& xx = data["A"];
   xx = 125.0; do_something(xx);
}

// T  = aRef( T*)   --> ok      
{
  std::cout<<" T = aRef( T*)... ";
   double xx = data["B"];
   xx = -521.0; do_something(xx);           // local !!
}

// const T& = aRef( T*)   --> ok    
{
  std::cout<<" const T& = aRef( T*)... ";
   const double& xx = data["A"];
   do_something(xx);
}

 const MDATA& cdata = data;

// T& = aRef( const T*)   --> not ok     
{
  std::cout<<" T& = aRef( const T*)... ";
   double& xx = cdata["A"];
   xx = 125.0; do_something(xx);
}

// T  = aRef(const T*)   --> ok      
{
  std::cout<<" T = aRef( const T*)... ";
   double xx = cdata["B"];
   xx = -521.0; do_something(xx);            // local !!
}

// const T& = aRef(const T*)   --> ok    
{
  std::cout<<" const T& = aRef( const T*)... ";
   const double& xx = cdata["A"];
   do_something(xx);
}

  return 0;

}
```

Now this is the result generated by gcc 11.1 :

```
|                             |                                                             |
| --------------------------- | ----------------------------------------------------------- |
|       T& = aRef( T*)        |  operator       T&()                                        |
|       T  = aRef( T*)        |  operator       T&()                                        |
| const T& = aRef( T*)        |  operator const T&()                                        |
|       T& = aRef( const T*)  |  operator       T&() ----> make compiler issue an error !!! |
|       T  = aRef( const T*)  |  operator       T&() ----> make compiler issue an error !!! |
| const T& = aRef( const T*)  |  operator const T&()                                        |
```

and the one generated by clang 11.1

```
|                             |                                                             |
| --------------------------- | ----------------------------------------------------------- |
|       T& = aRef( T*)        |  operator       T&()                                        |
|       T  = aRef( T*)        |  operator const T&()                                        |
| const T& = aRef( T*)        |  operator const T&()                                        |
|       T& = aRef( const T*)  |  operator       T&() ----> make compiler issue an error !!! |
|       T  = aRef( const T*)  |  operator const T&()                                        |
| const T& = aRef( const T*)  |  operator const T&()                                        |
```

As you can see , Clang give desired behavior and not Gcc, the proble is the call of conversion operator when assigning to value ( T = aRef(.) ) which is the const method for clang ( seems logical to me ) and other for Gcc.

So my questions :

1. is this normal behavior or Gcc defect ???
2. if this is normal, how can i manage to make Gcc get the wright overload ??

Comment: Can be simplified to [that](https://godbolt.org/z/d4Y8MfcK1)...

Comment: And then to [that](https://godbolt.org/z/3Th1fWPnn).

Comment: This is a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63217) (see particularly comment 5), but I don't know of any workaround.

Comment: Thank you guys for fast replies, I have to look for an other design then , because gcc is ous main compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sample can be simplified to:

```
struct S
{
    int n1 = 1;
    const int n2 = 2;
    //template<typename T> operator T&() { return n1; }
    template<typename T> operator const T&() { return n2; }
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    int n = s;
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

gcc gives

> error: cannot convert 'S' to 'int' in initialization

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Th1fWPnn)

And according to [Non-class_initialization_by_conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Non-class_initialization_by_conversion)

> the non-explicit user-defined conversion functions of S and its base classes (unless hidden) that produce type T or a type convertible to T by a standard conversion sequence, or a reference to such type. cv qualifiers on the returned type are ignored for the purpose of selecting candidate functions.

As I understand, only operator `int` or `int&` should be considered.

so gcc would be right but on the non-template version [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a95nY5YdG) both are viable...

Comment: This difference between literals and classes seems strange even if it complies with the rules.
anyway, that means that we can't rely on conversion operators as long as the results may vary between compilers !!!